# How to erase all special characters and replace non latin characters from a string in batch file

Tags: batch-file, replace, rename

I have the following batch file that works to delete the special characters. (not only #$@& that I give as example in code),  But my code is quite limited.

I need a batch file to delete from all filenames I have in a folder, all special characters at once and keep only [-A-Za-z ] , specifically "-", "A to Z", "a to z" and "blank spaces".
Besides that, I need to replace the non-Latin characters with Latin characters like   ĞğİıŞşÇçÖöÜü  with  GgIiSsCcOoUu

```
@echo off
Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

FOR %%G IN (*) DO (
    set "filename=%%~G"
    set "filename=!filename:@=!"
    set "filename=!filename:#=!"
    set "filename=!filename:$=!"
    set "filename=!filename:&=!"

    REM The list can continue with characters wanted to be removed

    IF NOT "!filename!" == "%%~G" ren "%%~G" "!filename!"

)
EndLocal
exit /b 0
```

Anyone can help me on this.
thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem Define sets of characters to delete/replace
set "delete=@#$&"        &  set "del=3"
set "find=ĞğİıŞşÇçÖöÜü"  &  set "len=11"
set "repl=GgIiSsCcOoUu"

for %%G in (*) do (

   set "filename=%%G"

   rem Delete characters
   for /L %%i in (0,1,%del%) do for %%a in ("!delete:~%%i,1!") do (
      set "filename=!filename:%%~a=!"
   )

   rem Replace characters
   for /L %%i in (0,1,%len%) do (
      for /F "tokens=1,2 delims=:" %%x in ("!find:~%%i,1!:!repl:~%%i,1!") do (
         set "filename=!filename:%%x=%%y!"
      )
   )

   if "!filename!" neq "%%G" ren "%%G" "!filename!"

)
```

**NOTE**: this is untested! I'm not sure if this code will directly work in your computer. Perhaps the non-Latin characters in the code may cause problems. If so, try to fix it by including a **`chcp 1252`** command at beginning...

Comment: I need to clean hundreds of files. A way to delete all special characters that are found with the exception of "-" and keep normal characters "A to Z", "a to z" and "blank spaces", will do the job, do you know something like this? Thank you

Comment: Why have you repeated your question in the above comment @IonutBejinariu? Is there a specific issue with the code submitted in the answer above? Have you ran it in a test directory of representative file names? What did or didn't happen according to your stated requirements?

Comment: I ran the script, it only works to delete the special characters specified in the batch file, it does not work to replace the non-Latin characters, with chcp 1252 also doesn work. The basic idea is that I need a different approach, because I have hundreds of files with dozens of emoticons, or other strange characters. For this reason I don't want to specify which characters to delete... I want it to delete everything it finds except "-" , "A to Z", "a to z" and "blank spaces".  Only non-latin characters to specify which to be replaced with. Hope I was more clear now..  thank you

Comment: Well, your _original_ question clearly specified: _"delete the special characters I choose"_ and your code, after removing `@#$&` characters as example, indicated: `REM The list can continue with characters wanted to be removed`. Are you changing your original specifications _NOW_? That is, after I spent my time trying to solve your problem? **`:(`**

Comment: I thought that the second paragraph on my description was clear about what I needed.. What was written in the code was what I managed to make work, but not what I need exactly.. Now I am very sorry, that you spent the time in a wrong direction..  trully sorry

Comment: basically the part with replacing non-Latin characters is in the way you did it, only not working for the moment in the way you did it..    The only part with miss understanding is the first part with special characters..  just need to be all erased with the exception of "-" , "A to Z", "a to z" and "blank spaces".. thank you!

Comment: I tried with map  
set "map=abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ 1234567890"
for %%G in (*) do (
   set "filename=%%G"

   rem Delete characters
   for /L %%i in (0,1,%del%) do 
     for /F "delims=*~ eol=*" %%a in ("!delete:~%%i,1!") do (
     if "!map:%%a=!" NEQ "!map!" set "filename=!filename:%%~a=!"
   )

but does'n work.. I am such a beginner on this